# How to convert base64 stream into string and write into another file?

Tags: node.js, base64

I am getting message stream from email body and this stream is in base64 formate I want to decode the stream.I am using 'base64-stream' which is npm module to decode the stream but I am getting error.

**TypeError: base64.decode is not a function**

```
   function buildAttMessageFunction(attachment) {
  var filename = attachment.params.name;
  var encoding = attachment.encoding;

  return function (msg, seqno) {
    var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
    msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      //Create a write stream so that we can stream the attachment to file;
      console.log(prefix + 'Streaming this attachment to file', filename, info);
      var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
      writeStream.on('finish', function() {
        console.log(prefix + 'Done writing to file %s', filename);
      });

      //stream.pipe(writeStream); this would write base64 data to the file.
      //so we decode during streaming using 
      if (toUpper(encoding) === 'BASE64') {
        //the stream is base64 encoded, so here the stream is decode on the fly and piped to the write stream (file)
        stream.pipe(base64.decode()).pipe(writeStream);
      } else  {
        //here we have none or some other decoding streamed directly to the file which renders it useless probably
        stream.pipe(writeStream);
      }
    });
    msg.once('end', function() {
      console.log(prefix + 'Finished attachment %s', filename);
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to use this way

```
const {Base64Decode} = require("base64-stream");
stream.pipe(new Base64Decode()).pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: Thank you for this!